# nedit command alias causes functional breakage

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I am using nedit to edit source code in my workstation. Yet, it starts with the following errors:

```
Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-o-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Cannot convert string "-*-courier-bold-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-o-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
```

Not knowing how to fix these errors, I used an alias to start edit:
ne='nedit &>/dev/null &'

It is to suppress the warning messages spit to stdout and stderr, and let nedit run in the background, so that I can type the next command in the current terminal window.

Yet, if I use this alias to open a file directly, it gives me an error msg like:

```
[qxu@merlin:/home/qxu/work/src]# ne abc.c
[4] 24969304
-bash: ./abc.c: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
```

Yet, `nedit abc.c` works, though with the above font error msgs.

Is there a way for me to use the above alias and give it a filename to open directly?

Comment: What happens when you run `type ne` as root?

Comment: @VictorHugo: ne is aliased to `nedit &>/dev/null &'

Comment: You could try to fix the problem instead of ignoring it: Does nedit have a configuration file where you have placed non-existent font names?

Comment: @glennjackman: This is in .nedit/nedit.rc - `nedit.textFont: -*-courier-medium-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1`. 3 more lines about the other three fonts. Basically all are "courier-***-iso8859-1", and should be present in my system. How could I check whether these fonts exist or not in my ubuntu system?

Comment: You could also fix this by installing the missing fonts. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149864/how-to-configure-x11-to-find-a-font-as-requested-by-a-proprietary-binary) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function instead of an alias. When we have to handle arguments, it is more simple to use. Place the following function in your `.bashrc` file:

```
function ne() {
    command nedit "$@" &>/dev/null &
}
```

In this example, when you run `ne file.txt`, you call this function which executes the command `nedit` with all the arguments you've passed (`"$@"`).

Take a look at this [explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/24320) of when you should use an alias or a function. It is very good

Comment: Awesome! By the way, why should we add "command" before "nedit" in the function body?

Comment: @QiangXu: it tells bash that `nedit` is a command to be executed. I'm glad it worked `:)`

Comment: @QiangXu, in a shell type `help command` -- it skips functions with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your alias is that you have `&` in the wrong place. When the alias is expanded you get

```
nedit &>/dev/null & abc.c
```

`&` is a [command separator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists), so this is equivalent to

```
nedit &>/dev/null &     # launch nedit in the background without a file to edit
abc.c                   # execute abc.c
```

and apparently "abc.c" does not have execute permissions.

As Victor said, use a function.